# Excel formula PERCENTILE and how it works with ranges i.e A:A

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have the Excel formula `PERCENTILE(A:A,0.01)`. I imagine that this range equals `A1:A65536` (or whatever is max). But would that mean that in its calculation of percentile it has a list of 65536 cells where most of them are empty? Or does it only construct a list which has cells with value?

How is the percentile implementation handled in Excel for ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question `A:A` represents the range of all of the values in the A column.

The [PERCENTILE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/percentile-HP005209211.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) function looks at all of the values and determines where the threshold is for your specified percentiles.

For example say you have a list of cells with values from 1 to 10. And you want to find where the 90 percentile begins. So create the function like:

```
=PERCENTILE(A1:A10,0.9)
```

This will return `9.1`. This means that any values at 9.1 or higher are in the 90th percentile.

You can read more about percentile [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile).